# What's wrong with my Spring Security setup?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I've setup my spring security, however, my HttpServletRequest no matter what, it's NOT an instance of SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.

It is interesting that if I use SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() directly, I'm able to get all the information I need.

Here is my debug code

```
     logger.debug("Test Permission using AwareRequestWrapper object");
    if (request instanceof SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper) {
        logger.debug("The request is an instance of SpringSecurityAwareRequestWrapper");
        SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper requestWrapper = 
                   (SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper) request;
        if(requestWrapper.isUserInRole("administrator"))
        {
            logger.debug("user is an admin");
        }
        else{
            logger.debug("user is a user");
        }

    }
    else{
        logger.debug("The request is NOT an instance of SpringSecurityAwareRequestWrapper");
    }

    logger.debug("Test using directi SecurityContextHolder");
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if(auth!=null)
    {
        logger.debug("Authenticaiton object is not null");
        baseResult = (LoginResult)auth.getPrincipal();
        if(baseResult.isAdmin())
        {
            logger.debug("user is an admin");
        }
        else{
            logger.debug("user is an user");
        }
    }
    else{
        logger.debug("Authentication object is null");
    }
```

Here is the result in log

```
2015-09-08 11:02:56,668 DEBUG [debugLogger] - Test Permission using AwareRequestWrapper object
2015-09-08 11:02:56,668 DEBUG [debugLogger] - The request is NOT an instance of SpringSecurityAwareRequestWrapper
2015-09-08 11:02:56,668 DEBUG [debugLogger] - Test using directi SecurityContextHolder
2015-09-08 11:02:56,668 DEBUG [debugLogger] - Authenticaiton object is not null
2015-09-08 11:02:56,668 DEBUG [debugLogger] - user is an admin
```

Here is my security.xml

```
<http auto-config="true" servlet-api-provision="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/css/*" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/images/*" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/js/*" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/*.ttf" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/fonts/*" access="permitAll"/>

        <intercept-url pattern="/Logout.jsp" access="permitALL" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/index" access="permitAll"/>


        <intercept-url pattern="/**/*" access="isAuthenticated()"/>

        <form-login 
            login-page="/"
            default-target-url="/home" 
            authentication-failure-url="/logout" 
            login-processing-url="/register"/>

        <csrf disabled="true"/>

    </http>

    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider"
                 class="mynamespace.CustomAuthenticationProvider" />

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>
```

[Edit]:

FYI. After I turned on Spring Security in the log, I did this

```
2015-09-08 12:22:19,634 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] - /home at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
```

So, the filter IS fired, so why can't my controller  get ahold of the SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to check and see that it actually _is_. It's possible its a subclass of `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper` in which case your test should be `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.class.isAssignableFrom()`

Answer (score 0):

Resolved..

Actually, in my web.xml, behind my SpringFilterChain, I have another filter which was taking over the request and such, I always get the wrong type..

Moved that filter up above the springfilter in web.xml, it's resolved.

Thank you.